# How do I combine XML codes for ARIS program?

Tags: xml, aris

Problem --> we want this result, but in one list

The problem is this, this is a table, with these settings;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XZy9I.png)

But we want this in a clickable list, like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4gRG.png)

For this we’ve built our own piece of XML code from scratch.
Now the second result is generated from this piece of code;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaXUZ.png)

So in essence, we want to combine the function “Superior functions” generated by this code;
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPo59.png)

And have the “risks” function to be executed then. How can we do this in a simple way? Thanks in advance,

Comment: XML is a text file that can be modified with any text editor or you can write an application to modify.  You first link is a tool to do the modifications.